# Translate a nested Conditional If Statement into a complex NSCompoundPredicate

Tags: if-statement, core-data, swiftui, swiftui-list, nscompoundpredicate

I'm writing a macOS target for an old iOS based project using SwiftUI. Is's a Core Data driven application and for the macOS target, I've successfully implemented generic List using a dynamic @FetchRequest, mostly as described by Paul Hudson in his [blog](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/dynamically-filtering-fetchrequest-with-swiftui).

I've primarily built the target by following Apple's [SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-a-macos-app) and copying the sample code provided.

The previously used conditional if statement actively filtered each SwiftUI `List` based on 3 UI controls.

[image: Image of three UI controls to "filter" the SwiftUI List]

```
// PART 1
    if (!self.appData.showFavouritesOnly
        || fetchedEvent.isFavourite)
// PART 2
    && (self.searchText.count == 0
        || (fetchedEvent.eventName?.contains(self.searchText) == true))
// PART 3
    && (self.filter == .all
        || self.filter.name == fetchedEvent.eventCategory
        || (self.filter.category == .featured && fetchedEvent.isFeatured)) {
```

Now that I have a generic @FetchRequest that uses predicates, I want to translate this conditional if statement into an `NSCompoundPredicate`.

I'll include the entire initialiser so you can see how the dynamic @FetchRequest is built, but it is the predicate that I require assistance with...

```
init(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor],
     searchKey: String,
     searchValue: String?,
     showFavourites: Bool,
     filterKey: String,
     filter: FilterType,
     @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (T) -> Content) {

    let entity = T.entity
    let predicateTrue = NSPredicate(value: true)
// PART 1
    let predicateFavourite = showFavourites == false ? predicateTrue : NSPredicate(format: "isFavourite == TRUE")
// PART 2
    let predicateSearch = searchValue?.count == 0 ? predicateTrue : NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchKey, searchValue!)

    // The initialiser works perfectly down to this point...then...
// PART 3
    let predicateFilterName = filter == .all ? predicateTrue : NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", filterKey, filter.name as CVarArg)
    let predicateFilterFeature = filter.category == .featured ? NSPredicate(format: "isFeatured == TRUE") : predicateTrue

    let predicateOr = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicateFilterName, predicateFilterFeature])
    let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicateFavourite, predicateSearch, predicateOr])

    fetchRequest =
        FetchRequest<T>(entity: entity,
                        sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors,
                        predicate: predicate)

    self.content = content
}
```

The code that is included here under Part 3 works partially. Switching between `FilterType.all` and `FilterType.featured` makes the expected changes, however I'm struggling to write the predicate for the "other" cases where another Category is chosen - that is - NOT Featured, but EITHER `.lakes`, `.rivers` or `.mountains`.

For completeness, I've also included the enum `Category` and struct `FilterType`...

```
enum Category: String, CaseIterable, Codable, Hashable {

    case featured = "Featured"
    case lakes = "Lakes"
    case rivers = "Rivers"
    case mountains = "Mountains"
}

struct FilterType: CaseIterable, Hashable, Identifiable {

    var name: String
    var category: Category?

    init(_ category: Category) {
        self.name = category.rawValue
        self.category = category
    }

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.category = nil
    }

    static var all = FilterType(name: "All")

    static var allCases: [FilterType] {
        return [.all] + Category.allCases.map(FilterType.init)
    }

    var id: FilterType {
        return self
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
 let predicateFilterFeature = filter.category == .featured ? NSPredicate(format: "isFeatured == TRUE") : predicateTrue
```

If the filter is `.lakes` etc, then this subpredicate will be TRUE, which when ORed with `predicateFilterName` overrides it.  Try returning FALSE:

```
 let predicateFilterFeature = filter.category == .featured ? NSPredicate(format: "isFeatured == TRUE") : predicateFalse
```

Comment: Thank you this works... a simple solution that works perfectly. I spent hours hacking away at this and should have stopped to think it through.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is a fraudulent answer because it is a hacked solution I stumbled across after trying to think about the construction of the predicates in a different manner. (It doesn't demonstrate any careful thought of the actual problem of understanding the syntax of the predicates that I had written!)

So this response doesn't answer my original question - that has been answered by @pbasdf - although this response achieves the same outcome.

So perhaps an alternate solution?!?

```
let predicateTrue = NSPredicate(value: true)

let predicateFavourite = showFavourites == false ? predicateTrue : NSPredicate(format: "isFavourite == TRUE")

let predicateSearch = searchValue?.count == 0 ? predicateTrue : NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchKey, searchValue!)

let predicateFilterFeatured = NSPredicate(format: "isFeatured == TRUE")
let predicateFilterName = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", filterKey, filter.name as CVarArg)
let predicateFilterCategory = filter.category == .featured ? predicateFilterFeatured : predicateFilterName

let predicateFilter = filter == .all ? predicateTrue : predicateFilterCategory

let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicateFavourite, predicateSearch, predicateFilter])
```